# share image using windows phone sdk v7.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am using `v7.1 sdk` for developing windows phone 8 application ( as my system doesn't support windows 8 so i cant use window phone 8 sdk). I want to share image . In windows phone 8 sdk it is possible using `SHAREMEDIATASK`. My question is that how can i share image using v7.1 , please help & understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you cannot use it on 7.1. I know is weird but the only way to do it is :

You can storage the image in Image Gallery and let the user share from there. Or you can upload the image to a remote server and share a link to the uploaded picture.

Comment: No. Those are the only ways, unfortunately

Comment: how about that if i saved that image in library and open it programmatically, from where user just have to click on share button ??

Comment: You mean, how you do it?

Comment: i mean how about that ? :P

Comment: well, I believe it is better then publishing the photo online which can be accessed by anyone. So yes, I would go with that.

Comment: thanks , one more question :P i'm saving image like this :
                
`MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary();
WriteableBitmap wbmp = new WriteableBitmap(canvas1, null); MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();System.Windows.Media.Imaging.Extensions.SaveJpeg(wbmp, ms, wbmp.PixelWidth, wbmp.PixelHeight, 0, 100);ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);library.SavePicture(string.Format("Images\\{0}.jpg", 0), ms);`
now how to open that image programmatically ?

Comment: Would be better for you to create another question for that :) The answer can be very long as a comment format.

Comment: ok @fiskerXO check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22563037/share-image-in-windows-phone)