# Share image in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am using v7.1 sdk for developing windows phone 8 application ( as my system doesn't support windows 8 so i cant use window phone 8 sdk). I want to share image . In windows phone 8 sdk it is possible using SHAREMEDIATASK but in windows phone sdk v7.1 it is not possible . Now the only solution is to save that image in library and open programmatically, i am doing it like this :

```
MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary(); 
WriteableBitmap wbmp = new WriteableBitmap(canvas1, null);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
System.Windows.Media.Imaging.Extensions.SaveJpeg(wbmp, ms, wbmp.PixelWidth, wbmp.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
library.SavePicture(string.Format("Images\\{0}.jpg", 0), ms);
```

At this point image has been saved , now how to open it progarmmatically ?

Comment: i want to open that image directly in picture library

Comment: Then you are right, that won't help. I'm deleting the comment. What do you mean by open it?

Comment: i want "to open the saved image"

Comment: Can you get a stream from MediaLibrary.Pictures ([article](http://debugmode.net/2012/02/04/accessing-pictures-from-media-library-in-windows-phone/)). Or use [PhotoChooserTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.photochoosertask(v=vs.105).aspx)?

Comment: It seems that you have not understand what i'm looking for . I dont want to show saved image in my application , i want to go to photos-->album-->saved pictures... thats it